# SOQL with 'like' is not returning data records correctly

Tags: soql, developer-console, bug

I've a query executed using `database.query()` method. The query looks like this:

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%admin, ray%' ORDER BY Name`

I can execute this query directly in 'Developer Console' and I get `0 results` as well.

But there is definitely a record named `Admin, Raymond` in `CustomObj__c`. There is `No Private Sharing` in the org. `CustomObj__c` is set to `Public Read/Write` setting.

The number of records is not too much in the object as well, approximately 14000 record exist in the custom object.

The record was created approximately 3 weeks back, so it should comes down to data not indexed. And plus I can search for this record in Salesforce Search as well as I can open up and access this record as well.

if I can query it like this:

**1 record returned:**

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%admin, %' ORDER BY Name`

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%admin%' ORDER BY Name`

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%ray%' ORDER BY Name`

**0 record returned:**

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%admin, ray%' ORDER BY Name`

Can someone point me if there is something wrong in query at all or could it be platform issue of sort?

**EDIT:**
Added a bit of code context: My query generation is like this:

```
list<sObject> lst = (list<sObject>)database.query( 'Select Id,'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' from '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(obj)+' where ' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' like \'%'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(q)+'%\'' );
```

And it results into following actual SOQL query:

`Select Id, Name from CustomObj__c WHERE Name like '%admin, ray%' ORDER BY Name`

Comment: I would suggest that it is something to do with having whitespace in the name. Are you sure you are using the same whitespace? Have you tried matching with '%admin%ray%;?

Comment: Are you sure the record returned when using '%ray%' is the same as the one returned by '%admin%'?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure, because my tool is using auto complete, and rest of the name shows up there as well in result in my query in many cases except the one highlighted above.

Comment: Are you using a binding variable when passing the match string to your query? Could you please [update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/280221/edit) your question and show the exact code you are using since it could be something more to do with how you construct the query rather than the specific query text that is at fault.

Comment: added my query generation code in query. But I'm still puzzled as I'm getting same result of no records from My Code and as well as from Developer Console SOQl execute.

Comment: If you change it to use the approach of constructing a binding for the LIKE match value like shown in the single answer does that help? Clearly you can still use dynamic SOQL, but the point is to create the match string and test it indirectly using the variable's name as the binding. In this context you must not try to escape the match string text.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you have **additional spaces** in between the words i.e. between `Admin` and `Raymond`. This space doesn't show up in the page layout nor in the developer console but when you `edit` that record it will display the additional spaces which prevents this records being caught in the `LIKE` query of the above mentioned SOQL.

So taking your same example, when I queried using below SOQL

```
Select Id, Name from Account WHERE Name like '%Admin, ray%' ORDER BY Name
```

It returned zero results

[image]

Now, when I changed the query to

```
Select Id, Name from Account WHERE Name like '%Admin%ray%' ORDER BY Name
```

This yielded a result, which showed name as `Admin, Raymond`. Note that there is no additional space displayed in developer console result.

[image]

Then when I when into the detail layout of Account, name is displayed as `Admin, Raymond`
[image]

But, when I edited `Account Name`, it displayed as below i.e. with additional spaces.

[image]

Now, I changed my SOQL to below i.e with additional spaces i.e copied value from edit mode.

```
Select Id, Name from Account WHERE Name like '%Admin,    ray%' ORDER BY Name
```

It yielded the results properly

[image]

**

### Conclusion

So to get the proper results, it would be better to replace the `spaces` in the search string with `%` i.e. you can replace your dynamic `SOQL` from below

```
list<sObject> lst = (list<sObject>)database.query( 'Select Id,'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' from '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(obj)+' where ' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' like \'%'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(q)+'%\'' );
```

with

```
list<sObject> lst = (list<sObject>)database.query( 'Select Id,'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' from '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(obj)+' where ' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(nameField)+' like \'%'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(q.replaceAll(' ', '%'))+'%\'' );
```

Note that I have added **replaceAll** in this code i.e. `string.escapeSingleQuotes(q.replaceAll(' ', '%'))`. This above dynamic query now will return the results with additional spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your SOQL. It should looks like the following in Apex:

```
 String str = '%admin, ray%'
 List<Cust_obj> accts = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Cust_obj WHERE Name LIKE :str];
```

Comment: Better to have "String match = '%admin, ray%'; List<Cust__c> custs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Cust__c WHERE Name LIKE :match];" What's more this approach will work directly if having to move to dynamic (rather than static) SOQL.

Comment: @PhilW fair enough. updated.

Comment: I think I'm past that. Coding wise, I had to use Dynamic APEX for dynamic nature of application. Plus, I'm not able to execute the query in Developer Console and return record as well, which kind of over shadow coding issues :(